# If L=$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}$ show that L=1/6

Tags: limits

> Let L=$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}$ by using the substitution $x=3\theta$ prove that $L=\frac{1}{9}\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta - \sin(\theta)}{\theta ^3}+\frac{4}{27}$ futhermore, $L=\frac{1}{6}$

I was able to do the first part easily using $\sin(3\theta)=3\sin(\theta)-4\sin^3(\theta)$, But for the second part I spent a significant amount of time and found a solution which I am not sure about it's correctness

So heres my solution for the second part,

Since $\theta = \frac{x}{3}$ we can get,

$$L=\frac{1}{9}\lim_{\frac{x}{3} \to 0} \frac{\frac{x}{3} - \sin(\frac{x}{3})}{(\frac{x}{3}) ^3}+\frac{4}{27}$$

If we continue doing what was done in the first part for infinite ($n$) times,

eg: $\frac{x}{3}=3\alpha$

$$\frac{x}{9}=3\beta$$

$$L=(\frac{1}{9})^n \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y-\sin(y)}{y^3} + \frac{4}{27}+(\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})+(\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})^2+(\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})^3 + \ldots + (\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})^n$$

Where $y$ is a very little value (because $y = \frac{x}{3^n}$)

As we all know when $y$ is a very little value, $\sin(y)=y$

$$(\frac{1}{9})^n \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y-\sin(y)}{y^3} = 0$$

(Though $y-\sin(y)=0$, $y\neq 0 $ as $y$ is a very little value therefore the function would not be undefined)

Hence we are left with,

$$L=\frac{4}{27}+(\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})+(\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})^2+(\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})^3 + \ldots + (\frac{4}{27})(\frac{1}{9})^n$$

From the sum of geometric series I got,

$L=\frac{1}{6}$ which is the answer I'm asked to show.

Could any of ya'll say whether have I done anything wrong in the solution (Because I feel so) and most importantly much simpler soultion than this (I know that there should be a much more simpler version than this but my dumbass can't figure it out)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, if the first part is proven, since $L=\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\theta-\sin(\theta)}{\theta^3}$, we have $L=\frac{1}{9}L+\frac{4}{27}$, which solves to $L=\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Oh god I didn't see it thank you very much .btw, what I've done in the soultion is correct?

Comment: The part that we are doing the first part for infinite number of time(n), and that $\frac{1}{9^n}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y-\sin(y)}{y^3}=0$ doesn't seem right. Even if we let the limit of $n\to \infty$, I still don't get the reason why we consider $n$ at the first place. The geometric series idea needs some clarification as why the series needs to converge at the first place(This would need more argument such as the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_n$ with $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{9}x_n+\frac{4}{27}$ would converge).

Comment: Getting rid of the limit involving $y$ isn't valid for the reason you gave.  Instead, you would want to note that the limit involving $y$ is just $L$ and then $L/9^n$ tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.  That factor of $1/9^n$ is the only reason you can disregard the limit involving $y$, and only as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: If you use maclaurin series, then you can directly compute the limit.

Answer (score 1):

In $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}$, $x$ can be replaced by any other variable, so $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\theta - \sin(\theta)}{\theta ^3}=L$.

So after the first part, you know: $L = \dfrac 1 9 L + \dfrac 4 {27}$. Which immediately gives $\dfrac {8L} 9 = \dfrac 4 {27} \implies L=\dfrac 1 {2\times3} = \dfrac  1 6\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: Please don't use the exclamation mark after L.